# Jquery - $.each link in object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

I have the following API example:

```
"urls": [
{
"value": "http://twitter.com"
},
{
"value": "http://gplus.to"
},
{
"value": "http://plus.ly"
},
{
"value": "http://glpl.us"
},
{
"value": "http://microsoft.ms/+"
},
{
"value": "https://plus.google.com",
"type": "profile"
},
{
"value": "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people",
"type": "json"
}
]
```

How can I use `.each()` to display each href from the link value in the object?

Also how can I exclude the values with `type = profile` and `type = json`?

I've tried:

```
  var yourLinks = data.urls;

  $.each(yourLinks, function(key, value) { 
    alert(key + ': ' + value); 
  });
```

But the alert just contains `object : object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alert(value.value); //<<<try that
```

Or more verbose:

```
  var yourLinks = data.urls;

  $.each(yourLinks, function(index, vals) { 
    alert(index + ":" + vals.value); 
  });
```

Comment: Any idea how I can also select based on the type: json as well?

Comment: @CLiown  `if(vals.type != undefined && vals.type == 'something'){...}`

Answer (score -1):

What's happening is that each element of `data.urls` is an object, so you basically need to run a double-each to get the key/value pairs for each one:

```
$.each(data.urls, function(index, obj) {
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    alert(key + ': ' + value);
  });
});
```